# .NET Core Blazor - The command "dotnet ..." Exited with code 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I have a solution consisting of several .NET Core (2.1) projects and a web solution written in Blazor (0.4.0).

I have just started getting the error below:

> Error MSB3073 The command "dotnet "C:\Users\YYY.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.4.0\targets../tools/illink/illink.dll" -c link -u link -t --verbose  -d "C:\Users\YYY.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.4.0\targets../tools/mono/bcl/" -d "C:\Users\YYY.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.4.0\targets../tools/mono/bcl/Facades/" -o "C:\TFS2\BAP - Desktop\Main\Source\Code\Framework.Desktop\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor/linker/" -x "C:\Users\YYY.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.4.0\targets\BuiltInBclLinkerDescriptor.xml" -x "C:\TFS2\BAP - Desktop\Main\Source\Code\Framework.Desktop\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker.descriptor.xml" -a "C:\Users\YYY.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor\0.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.dll" -a "C:\Users\YYY.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.browser\0.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.localization.abstractions\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.componentmodel.annotations\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" -a "C:\TFS2\BAP - Desktop\Main\Source\Code\BlazorDevExtreme\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\BlazorDevExtreme.dll" -a "C:\TFS2\BAP - Desktop\Main\Source\Code\XXXXXX.IdentityProvider.Model\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\XXXXXX.IdentityProvider.Model.dll" -a "C:\TFS2\BAP - Desktop\Main\Source\Code\XXXXXX.Utilities\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\XXXXXX.Utilities.dll" -a "C:\TFS2\BAP - Desktop\Main\Source\Code\XXXXXX.ServiceLayer.Analytic.Web\Lib\DevExpress.CodeParser.v18.1.dll" -a "C:\TFS2\BAP - Desktop\Main\Source\Code\Framework.Constants\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Framework.Constants.dll" -a "C:\TFS2\BAP - Desktop\Main\Source\Code\Framework.Shared\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Framework.Shared.dll" -a "C:\TFS2\BAP - Desktop\Main\Source\Code\XXXXXX.ServiceLayer.Analytic.Web\Lib\DevExpress.Data.v18.1.dll" -a "C:\TFS2\BAP - Desktop\Main\Source\Code\Framework.Desktop\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Framework.Desktop.dll"" exited with code 1.   Framework.Desktop   C:\Users\YYY.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.4.0\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets 441

I really have no idea why this has started to happen.

I know it's very difficult for anyone to solve - but if you can point me in a direction of why an error like this occurs then I might be able to solve it :)

I have tried to clean/rebuild and the PC has also been turned of and on several times, but the error persists.

Any ideas? Is it related to .NET Core?

Comment: When exactly does this error occur?

Comment: It happens when I build the solution.

Comment: And it is the Blazor project that fails? What happens on a 'dotnet build' on the command line for that project?

Comment: I ran the command you suggested and it actually gave me some information that I did not get when doing a standard build from visual studio. Now I have a concrete error to solve so that makes it a bit easier, thanks for the help m8! have a good day ;)

Comment: Please post the answer if you found it, maybe it will help others.

Answer (score 2):

After running dotnet build on the project that was failing I got a concrete error and discovered that there were some errors in my .csproj file.

For some reason some ItemGroup elements were inserted automatically:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="DevExpress.CodeParser.v18.1">
      <HintPath>..\XXX.ServiceLayer.Analytic.Web\Lib\DevExpress.CodeParser.v18.1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="Components\FormGroupRowLabeledDateBox\FormGroupRowLabeledDateBox.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Components\FormGroupRowLabeledTextBox\FormGroupRowLabeledTextBox.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

By removing the above from my failing .csproj file the error was gone.

Comment: Ok. There was a bug about this (fixed in 0.4): https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/316. But this sounds like you have done something different. Maybe you should report it..